# Shorter Generics Syntax in SwiftUI Views

Tags: swiftui

Are there any better syntax for generics? Belowed code gives me huge ugly generics definition in the beginning of view.

```
struct ViewUserSettings<TypeGif: ModelGifProtocol, TypeFont: ModelFontProtocol, TypeMagicText: ModelMagicTextProtocol, TypePreSetAnswer: ModelPreSetAnswerProtocol>: View where TypeGif: Hashable, TypeFont: Hashable, TypeMagicText: Hashable, TypePreSetAnswer: Hashable
```

I had to define `Hashable` inside generics otherwise compiler gives Error when I tried to use this Protocol in SwiftUI ForEach.

*ModelGif.swift*

```
// MARK: - Protocol
enum GifType: String, Codable {
    
    case fooA = "fooA more"
    case fooB = "fooB more"
    case fooC = "fooC more"
    
    // MARK: Properties
    var fileName600px: String {
        switch self {
        case .fooA: return "fooAHQ"
        case .fooB: return "fooBHQ"
        case .fooC: return "fooCHQ"
        }
    }
    
    var fileName80px: String {
        switch self {
        case .fooA: return "fooALQ"
        case .fooB: return "fooBLQ"
        case .fooC: return "fooCLQ"
        }
    }
    
}

protocol ModelGifProtocol: Codable {
    var gif: GifType { get }
}

// MARK: - Module
struct ModelGif: ModelGifProtocol, Hashable {
    
    // MARK: Properties
    let gif: GifType
    
    // MARK: Initialization
    init(_ gif: GifType) {
        self.gif = gif
    }
    
    // MARK: Static Properties
    static var fooA = Self(.fooA)
    static var fooB = Self(.fooB)
    static var fooC = Self(.fooC)
    
}
```

*ModelMagicText.swift*

```
// MARK: - Protocol
protocol ModelMagicTextProtocol: Codable {
    var id: UUID { get }
    var context: String { get }
    init(_ context: String, id: UUID) throws
    init(_ context: String) throws
}

// MARK: - Module
struct ModelMagicText: ModelMagicTextProtocol, Hashable {
    
    // MARK: Properties
    let id: UUID
    let context: String
    
    // MARK: Initialization
    init(_ context: String, id: UUID) throws {
        guard context.count <= 30 else { throw ContextError.tooLong } // restricted at ViewAnimatingCircleText.modifyDynamicText()
        self.context = context.uppercased()
        self.id = id
    }
    
    init(_ context: String) throws {
       try self.init(context, id: UUID())
    }
    
    init(_ model: ModelMagicTextProtocol) throws {
        try self.init(model.context, id: model.id)
    }
    
    // MARK: Static Properties
    static let defaultText = try! ModelMagicText("foooooooooooo")
    
}

// MARK: - Extension: ContextError
extension ModelMagicText {
    
    enum ContextError: Error {
        case tooLong
    }
    
}
```

Comment: rob mayoff covers some of this, but to reinforce: If you have 4 type parameters, it's pretty likely you've over-done your protocols. Do you really need all these protocols, and do they all need associated types (I assume they have them, given the generic)? Often, this suggests over-designing the problem. Do all these protocols have multiple (shipping, not just for testing) implementations? Should some of these be functions rather than protocols? Have you made all of this much more generic than your problem actually requires?

Comment: I was going to bring up whether they need associated types, but since he also requires `Hashable`, I realized he can't use existentials or a “bag of closures” approach. It definitely smells overly generic though.

Comment: @RobNapier as you said that's really over engineered because I am asked to be applied SOLID principles all over the app so that I had to pass abstractions to the views.  I am taking these models into **ForEach** and select them by **Picker** that forced me to inherit them from `Hashable`.

Comment: Creating unnecessary protocols is not SOLID. SOLID does not require the creation of *unnecessary* abstraction. You do not make String parameters generic (open) just to match SOLID, and SOLID specifically calls for client-specific interfaces which suggests very small and simple interfaces rather than convoluted ones (why does everyone forget the "I"). That said, SOLID was created explicitly and intentionally in response to problems in common OOP languages of its time. Swift is not, at heart, an OOP language. It is a POP language, and calls for different approaches. Fighting Swift is not Swifty.

Comment: @OguzYuksel: Maybe you can correct your question title and gave more info about the issue, your question title doesn't make sense to me. Because every one use Generic in view here or there, no big deal.

Comment: @swiftPunk now seems more clear I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can format that more readably using multiple lines. We can also move the `Hashable` constraints into the generic parameter list:

```
struct ViewUserSettings<
    TypeGif: ModelGifProtocol & Hashable,
    TypeFont: ModelFontProtocol & Hashable,
    TypeMagicText: ModelMagicTextProtocol & Hashable,
    TypePreSetAnswer: ModelPreSetAnswerProtocol & Hashable
>: View {
    var gif: TypeGif
    var font: TypeFont
    var magicText: TypeMagicText
    var preSetAnswer: TypePreSetAnswer

    var body: some View { EmptyView() }
}
```

You only need a `where` clause when you have equality constraints, but your example code doesn't have any equality constraints.

If you change each of your model protocols to inherit from `Hashable`, you can eliminate the `Hashable` constraints entirely:

```
protocol ModelGifProtocol: Hashable { }
protocol ModelFontProtocol: Hashable { }
protocol ModelMagicTextProtocol: Hashable { }
protocol ModelPreSetAnswerProtocol: Hashable { }

struct ViewUserSettings<
    TypeGif: ModelGifProtocol,
    TypeFont: ModelFontProtocol,
    TypeMagicText: ModelMagicTextProtocol,
    TypePreSetAnswer: ModelPreSetAnswerProtocol
>: View {
    ...
```

There's also the question of whether you need such verbose names. Do you really need the `Type` and `Model` prefixes?

```
protocol GifProtocol: Hashable { }
protocol FontProtocol: Hashable { }
protocol MagicTextProtocol: Hashable { }
protocol PreSetAnswerProtocol: Hashable { }

struct ViewUserSettings<
    Gif: GifProtocol,
    Font: FontProtocol,
    MagicText: MagicTextProtocol,
    PreSetAnswer: PreSetAnswerProtocol
>: View {
    var gif: Gif
    var font: Font
    var magicText: MagicText
    var preSetAnswer: PreSetAnswer
    
    var body: some View { EmptyView() }
}
```

Keep in mind that you can still refer to SwiftUI's `Font` type as `SwiftUI.Font` inside `ViewUserSettings`.

You didn't give any details regarding how your protocols are defined. Do you really need your own `ModelFontProtocol`? SwiftUI's `Font` is already `Hashable`, so if you can just use the concrete `Font` type, your code will be simpler. Maybe you can use concrete types in place of your other protocols too, but we can't say without seeing how they're defined.

If you're using the same set of type parameters and constraints for multiple views, there are ways to factor the common stuff out. You should edit your question to include more example code if that's the case.

Comment: Thats great cover! all of my models are used in database, it is totally different than framework `Font` my ModelFont has a `fontFile: String` property so it reads custom fonts from Assets. My design is over engineered because it is asked to be applied all SOLID principles.

Comment: If your `ModelFontProtocol` has just a single `fontFont` requirement, then you would be better off using a `typealias` or a simple `struct` or [the `Tagged` package](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-tagged) to wrap that `String`.